# how to insert comment data for each thread data row in table one, using form for table two in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

sorry for my broken english. i'm trying to make a forum like page using mysql and php. i create 2 table, post and comment.
at my page, user can post a thread and also can post comment for the thread. i have no problem for posting a thread. for posting a comment, i got an error. and, if i could, for each thread, i can post many comment. here is my code:

**EDIT**

here is forum_comment_add.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","forum");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id ='".$post_id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<table width="710" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td width="708"><form name="comment_insert" method="post" action="forum_comment_add_go.php">
  <table width="398" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th width="24" scope="col">NO</th>
      <th width="90" scope="col">DATE</th>
      <th width="68" scope="col">TIME</th>
      <th width="198" scope="col">COMMENT</th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input name="date" type="text" id="date" size="15" /></td>
      <td><input name="time" type="text" id="time" size="10" maxlength="9" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="thread_comment" id="thread_comment" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="right"><?php echo "<input type='hidden' value='" . $rows['post_id'] . "' name='post_id'>"; echo "<input type='submit' value='Add Record'>";?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and forum_comment_add_go.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CloseWindow() {
    window.close(); 
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
</script>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","forum");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$thread_comment = $_POST['thread_comment'];
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$comment_in="INSERT INTO comment ( date, time, thread_comment, post_id) VALUES ( '$date', '$time', '$thread_comment', '$post_id)";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $comment_in);

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<th><form>";
echo "<input type='button' onClick='CloseWindow()' value='Done' align='middle'>";
echo "</form></th>";
}   
else {
echo "Error";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

for table post, PK = post_id and for table comment, PK = id with FK = post_id refer to PK in table post. what i'm trying to do is when i view any thread, i can post comments for the tread. can anyone help me. i'm stuck in posting comment.

Comment: can you reduce your code down to just what is use to post a comment. That is a lot of code to try to read through

Comment: @Sean, i thought people need to see all the code. sorry. should i remove other code?

Comment: Yes, only provide the code that relates directly to your question/issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, your insert query has single quotes placed wrong around your variables -

```
$comment_in="INSERT INTO comment ( date, time, thread_comment) VALUES ( $'date', $'time', $'thread_comment')";
```

should be

```
$comment_in="INSERT INTO comment ( date, time, thread_comment) VALUES ( '$date', '$time', '$thread_comment')";
```

Second, I don't see where you are setting those variables - `$date`, `$time`, `$thread_comment` in `forum_comment_add_go.php` before inserting them.

Third, when inserting your comment, you are not including the post id that the comment relates to.

So it your code may be something like -

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$thread_comment = $_POST['thread_comment'];
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$comment_in="INSERT INTO comment ( date, time, thread_comment, post_id) VALUES ( '$date', '$time', '$thread_comment', '$post_id)";
```

note, you are open to sql injection, as you are directly inserting user values without sanitizing. take a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thanks. i'm almost forgot to declare those variable. i'm trying by following your code, but its still go to error result. and my DB still empty.

Comment: did you means by updating my question with new code? cause at this comment field cant post too much words.

Comment: yes meant to say update your question with your updated code.

Comment: try adding `mysqli_error()` to your error message to find out why it is not inserting -> `else { echo "Error - ". mysqli_error($con); }`. Could be a syntax error, column names not spelled correctly, etc.